# Button onclick and everything disappears

Tags: javascript, html, buttonclick

I have been trying to write a code that simulates this example (code below).

```js
function closeMe(){

     x=document.getElementById("demo");

     x.style.display="none";

 }

function openMe(){

     x=document.getElementById("demo");

      x.style.display="block";

 }
```

```html
 <h1>Changing the Style</h1>
 <p>JavaScript can change the style of an HTML element.</p>

 <button type="button" onclick="openMe()">Open!</button>
 <button type="button" onclick="closeMe()">Close!</button>

 <p id="demo">Extra details...You can open and close this paragraph using the buttons above.</p>
```

Unfortunately, in my own code below, when I click the "open" button, all things just disappear. I can't figure out why.

```js
function open() {
  x = document.getElementById("demo");
  x.style.display = "block";
}

function close() {
  x = document.getElementById("demo");
  x.style.display = "none";
}
```

```html
<p id="demo">Click me to change my HTML content (innerHTML).</p>

<p> this shouldnt disappear</p>

<button onclick="open()">open button</button>

<button onclick="close()">close button</button>
```

Can anyone give me some kind advice?

Comment: sorry english is a second language to me and I am trying hard to master it... but still, thanks for your comments! ;)

Comment: I see. Trendy bad English by teenagers who can write good English, but won't, sometimes appears on this site. They write as though a Stackoverflow question were an SMS phone message to their immature friends. Such was not your intent. I will edit your post for standard English style.

Comment: @thb Many thanks for your editing, making more people to understand and benefit from this post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open & close are reserved keywords. You are required to rename close & open method.

The open() method opens a new browser window.

The close() method to close the window.

Comment: @SimonF I have added the answer here separately so it can help others.

Answer (score 3):

When setting the display to block, add quotes around "block"

```
function open(){
    x=document.getElementById("demo");
    x.style.display="block";
}
```

Comment: Hello BMac413, thanks for your comment! so I just edited to add the quotes to my code, and it seems still not working, i guess i have made some more mistakes..

Comment: @SimonF change your method name to something else from open & close. for example: openFunc(), closeFunc()

Comment: @devdev It worked!  and thanks to your comments, i checked and found those are "reserved words".  Many thanks

Comment: devedv is right. `open` and `close` are existing functions of the window object.

Answer (score 2):

Your function names are already being used. Keeping your code unchanged except for the function names you can test that is all works as expected.

```js
  function open123(){
    let x=document.getElementById("demo");
    x.style.display="block";
  }

  function close123(){
    let x=document.getElementById("demo");
    x.style.display="none";
  }
```

```html
<p id="demo">Click me to change my HTML content (innerHTML).</p>

<p> this shouldnt disappear</p>

<button onclick="open123()">open button</button>

<button onclick="close123()">close button</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

So these functions are all in the window scope, so i called window.function name.
I also declared the variable in the function as it was throwing some javascript errors.

Now these aren't usually required but I have a feeling that jsfiddle uses "use strict"; which may force these sorts of distinctions. However I am open to other suggestions.

Hope this helps.

```js
function open() { 
  var x = document.getElementById("demo");
  x.style.display = "block";
}

function close() {
  var x = document.getElementById("demo");
  x.style.display = "none";
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <p id="demo">Click me to change my HTML content (innerHTML).</p>

  <p> this shouldnt disappear</p>

  <button onclick="window.open();">open button</button>

  <button onclick="window.close();">close button</button>
</body>

</html>
```

---

Answer (score 1):

you need to use capital letters in functions and the styles must be between quotes;

try to have a clean code :)

```
function Open(){
        x = document.getElementById("demo");
        x.style.display = "block";
    }

        function Close(){
        x = document.getElementById("demo");
        x.style.display = "none";
    }
```

Comment: This code won't fix it's problem. the capital letters on functions won't help.

Answer (score 1):

open() and close() is reserved keyword.
Please change the function name like openOne() and closeOne() and it's work.